# How can I send random pdf files in email from a folder using Python?

Tags: python, email, attachment, mime, smtplib

I am trying to create an email bot that will send me a random pdf file from a folder. Though my code is not showing any error, I am not getting any mail. It'd be helpful if you can show me where I am going wrong and what should I do. Thank you.

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import  MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders
import os
import random
def send():
    body = ""
    sender_email = "email"
    password = "my_password"
    receiver_email = "email"

    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['Subject'] = '[Email Test]'
    msg['From'] = sender_email
    msg['To'] = receiver_email
    msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))
    path = "C:/Users/Asus/PycharmProjects/messenger_bot/files"
    files = os.listdir(path)
    index = random.randrange(0, len(files))
    print(files[index])
    attachment = open(os.path.join(path, random.choice(files)), 'rb')

    payload = MIMEBase('application', 'octate-stream')
    # payload = MIMEBase('application', 'pdf', Name=pdfname)
    payload.set_payload(attachment.read())

    # enconding the binary into base64
    encoders.encode_base64(payload)

    # add header with pdf name
    payload.add_header('Content-Decomposition', 'attachment', filename=files)
    msg.attach(payload)

    # use gmail with port
    session = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)

    # enable security
    session.starttls()

    # login with mail_id and password
    session.login(sender_email, password)

    text = msg.as_string()
    session.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, text)
    session.quit()
    print('Mail Sent')
```

Comment: Your code is missing indents, is that how you're executing it or is it just StackOverflow formatting error ?

Comment: I gave proper indentation. It's actually a formatting error.

Comment: Please don't sign me up for this "service".

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the sender email is correct?
change the sender_email from "email" to your actual email and it should work

Comment: I changed it into "email" for posting it here.

Answer (score 0):

From what I gather from [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html). The issue you are having is because starttls takes a keyfile and a certfile together or a context by itself and you haven't given either.

try adding this:

```
context = ssl.create_default_context()
```

and then change your starttls() call to

```
starttls(context=context)
```